# Combine client_credentials and Custom authentication flow in Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

Wondering if it's possible to combine using the client credentials OAuth flow in Cognito with a custom authentication flow as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-challenge.html

Answer (score 1):

I know about custom authentication flows in Cognito, but I am not so well versed in OAuth itself. But as far as I understand it, the client credentials flow, is unrelated to a user? Because in that case, I would think it is impossible to use a custom authentication flow since the SDK documentation states the following ([taken from the AWS node.js SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property)):

> The authentication parameters. These are inputs corresponding to the AuthFlow that you are invoking. The required values depend on the value of AuthFlow:
>   [...] For CUSTOM_AUTH: USERNAME (required)

If the value passed as `USERNAME` in the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow is not a known user in Cognito, the lambda trigger for the custom flow will never be executed. And since it is never executed, it is not possible to use the `USERNAME` parameter to pass any other data to the lambda trigger (you can of course use custom authentication parameters, but you also need a valid `USERNAME`).